# C segmentation fault using malloc'ed strings

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf, strcpy

Essentially, I have a structure for a linked list in my code,

```
struct node{
  char* val;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Then later I try to do some things to it...

```
...
addr = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
addr->val = malloc(72);
addr->val = "";
snprintf(addr->val, 1000, "%s", ident);
...
```

...
This gives me a segmentation fault at the snprintf.  Valgrind says the following

```
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==10724==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x40566B
==10724==    at 0x4EB0A32: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:112)
==10724==    by 0x4E8F931: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==10724==    by 0x4016CC: id (Analyzer.c:267)
...
```

I am fairly new to C as opposed to C++, but I thought that calling malloc on the char* should make it valid, especially since I can initialize and print it, so I don't understand why the snprintf wouldn't work.
I also had my program print out the addresses of both variables, and the address valgrind complains about is indeed from addr->val.

I also tried using strcpy instead of snprintf but had the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addr->val = malloc(72);
```

This line dynamically allocates 72 bytes and assigns the address of that memory region to `addr->val`.

```
addr->val = "";
```

This then sets `addr->val` to point to the address of a string constant, discarding the address of the malloced area of memory that it previously contained, causing a memory leak.

When you then try to use `snprintf`, you're attempting to write to a string literal.  Since these are typically stored in a read-only section of memory, attempting to do so results in a core dump.

There's no need for `addr->val = "";`.  It throws away allocated memory; it doesn't set that allocated memory to an empty string, which is probably what you thought it would do.  Even if it did, it's useless anyway because `snprintf` will overwrite anything that might be there.

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
addr->val = malloc(72);
addr->val = "";             <====
```

overwrites `val` pointer with "", address of a static area, made of 1 character (of value 0). Remove this line.

And

```
snprintf(addr->val, 1000, "%s", ident);
```

Accept a length of 1000 while you only allocated 72 characters.

```
snprintf(addr->val, 72, "%s", ident);
```

is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
addr->val = malloc(72);
addr->val = "";
```

The second line re-assignes `addr->val` to an address in read-only section (where string literals lie), and discards the address of allocation from `malloc`, which can lead to a potential memory leak.

I know you want to clear it. To assign strings, you should use `strcpy()`

```
strcpy(addr->val, "");
```

But since you want to empty it, it's easiest to set the first character to zero:

```
addr->val[0] = '\0';
```

Besides, you're trying to do a potentially harmful job:

```
snprintf(addr->val, 1000, "%s", ident);
```

You intended to allocate 72 bytes, but why us the second parameter going up to 1k? Change it to a safer number:

```
snprintf(addr->val, 72, "%s", ident);
```

Everything should be fine by then.